# Relabelling predictors with jtools effect_plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to edit the names of the factor levels of a predictor variable in R for an effect plot with the jtools package. I should be able to do this with the "pred.labels" argument, but the labels don't change. For example, using the mtcars data set I try to write out the predictor names ("four", "six", "eight") but there is no change in the figure.

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtest <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
effect_plot(mtest, pred = cyl, pred.labels = c("four", "six", "eight"))
```

[image: Figure produced with above script, where labels have NOT been changed]

Now, if this were really my problem I would just overwrite the factor levels in the data. However, in my data set I have many factors that should have a space in their name for easy interpretation, so I don't want to recode my variables this way. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: So is your problem just that `pred.labels` isn't working?

Comment: yes either it's not working or I'm using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `jtools` seems to use `ggplot2` you can just change the labels like you would if you were using `ggplot2`

```
label <- c("four", "six", "eight")
effect_plot(mtest, pred = cyl) + scale_x_discrete(labels= label)
```

or

```
effect_plot(mtest, pred = cyl) + scale_x_discrete(labels= c("four", "six", "eight"))
```

[image: example]

Comment: That works - thank you!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to rename the group labels in jtools but you can do it with `scale_x_discrete` in ggplot2 since the resulting object is from ggplot.

```
effect_plot(mtest, pred = cyl) +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = c("four", "six", "eight"))
```

[image: output]